# Circular dependencies in c++

Tags: c++, include, circular-dependency

Say I have these two classes:

```
// a.h

#include "b.h"
```

and:

```
// b.h

include "a.h"
```

I understand there is a problem over here, but how can I fix it and use `a` objects and their methods in `b` class and vice versa?

Comment: The Ghost of StackOverflow says, "*Uhhhhhhnnnn... Neeeeed moooore cooooode......*"

Comment: I don't see any classes in there, so I'm downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use forward declarations, like this:

```
class B;

class A
{
    B* ThisIsValid;
}

class B
{
    A SoIsThis;
}
```

For more information, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration) SO question.

As for the preprocessor `#include`s, there's likely a better way to organize your code.  Without the full story, though, it's hard to say.

Comment: I've seen it where the simplest model was forward declaring it in the header files.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on @Borealid 's answer:

> To avoid problems with circular includes, using an "include guard"

eg.

```
#ifndef MYFILE_H /* If this is not defined yet, it must be the first time
 we include this file */
#define MYFILE_H // Mark this file as already included
// This only works if the symbol we are defining is unique.

// code goes here

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use what is called a "forward declaration".

For a function, this would be something like `void myFunction(int);`. For a variable, it might look like `extern int myVariable;`. For a class, `class MyClass;`. These bodiless statements can be included before the actual code-bearing declarations, and provide the compiler with enough information to produce code making use of the declared types.

To avoid problems with circular includes, using an "include guard" - an `#ifdef` at the top of each header file which prevents it being included twice.

Comment: This answer doesn't discuss the real core of the thing, which is that you restrict your mention of `B` in `A`'s header to forward declarable things, but in `A`'s source file you are free to `#include` the full definition because nothing is going to `#include` the source file... you're not going to have any circular dependencies with it. This _only_ affects headers, and that's how we can make use of an approach that effectively cripples use of a type.

Answer (score 0):

The "other" class can only have a reference or pointer to the "first" class.

in file a.h:

```
#include "b.h"

struct a {
    b m_b;
};
```

in file b.h:

```
struct a;

struct b {
    a* m_a;
};

void using_the_a_instance(b& theb);
```

in file b.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

void using_the_a_instance(b& theb)
{
    theb.m_a = new a();
}
```